# Translation (CAT) software that exports bilingual content

Tags: software-rec, language

I looked at various Open Source translation software (desktop OR web like: weblate, omegaT, pootle, etc.) and I cannot find this 'feature' or I am incorrectly searching to find it or it doesn't exist.

I want to be able to translate text from source language (English) to target language (Spanish) and then **export this text as bilingual content as PDF or HTML or any other format.**

For example this type of layout (per sentence/string OR per paragraph) is what I want:

```
I am a boy
Soy un niño

My name is John
Mi nombre es John

I am 10 years old
Tengo 10 años
```

OR:

```
I am a boy. My name is John. I am 10 years old.
Soy un niño. Mi nombre es John. Tengo 10 años.

<para 2 English>
<para 2 Spanish>
```

Comment: This is way too broad a question, but....1. find a translation tool that processes stdin and prints the result immediately - without buffering - to stdout.  2. using a language that can open a bidirectional pipe (i.e. can simultaneously Read AND Write to it - e.g. Perl's [IPC::Open3](https://perldoc.perl.org/IPC::Open3)), pipe one paragraph or sentence at a time into it and read the result.  3. Save both to a file in whatever format you like. 4. Alternatively, find a translation tool with an API so that you can write your own tool using their translation library in your preferred prog language

Comment: What you said is confusing. I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: in short: if the software doesn't do exactly what you want, then write a wrapper script that feeds it one sentence at a time.